When describing motion in terms of proper time, what is the default reference frame?
So in general relativity, motion of objects in the flat spacetime is parameterized by $(t(\tau), x(\tau), y(\tau), z(\tau))$ where $\tau$ is proper time. One thing is not clear to me is what is the default frame of reference for coordinates $(t, x, y, z)$. Can the origin of the default reference frame be the origin of an object's inertial frame so that $x(\tau)=0, y(\tau)=0, z(\tau)=0$ for all $\tau$? Or it can be the origin of an inertial reference frame that moves in constant speed with respect to an object's inertial frame along negative x-direction?

And in your example also $t(\tau)=\tau$

Well, you probably misunderstood the theory. The length axes are not functions of time in the strict sense. (How is time axis a function of time itself??)

@PatoGalmarini Why? I thought it is always true that $t>\tau$.

A clock measures its own proper time

If it's GR, you don't need to assume flat spacetime

The "default" reference frame is any inertial frame in which the object is stationary!

The reference frame for the $(x, y, z, t)$ can be anything.  It could be the rest frame of the object, as you mention.  In general, there is no default frame of reference; the specific problem that is being solved should make clear what coordinates to use.  Depending on the scenario, there might be a certain set of coordinates that are most natural, like the surface of the earth being stationary and with time being measured with standard clocks.
